# Why read_utf8() gives TypeError: '<' not supported between instances of 'int' and 'NoneType' in Apache Beam/ python

Tags: python, google-cloud-dataflow, pipeline, apache-beam, batch-processing

I was following the [doc](https://www.stackoverflow.com/) and wanted to access filename and content when reading text files. I have the text files in GCP storage, (in compressed format - gzip) while trying to read the files it gives me the error as below:

```
Error message from worker: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "apache_beam/runners/common.py", line 1417, in apache_beam.runners.common.DoFnRunner.process
  File "apache_beam/runners/common.py", line 624, in apache_beam.runners.common.SimpleInvoker.invoke_process
  File "/home/dc/.virtualenvs/bots/lib/python3.8/site-packages/apache_beam/transforms/core.py", line 1845, in <lambda>
    wrapper = lambda x: [fn(x)]
  File "/home/dc/office_projects/BI-pipelines/bots_dataflows/templates/adjust_events_dataflow.py", line 94, in <lambda>
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/apache_beam/io/fileio.py", line 232, in read_utf8
    return self.open().read().decode('utf-8')
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/apache_beam/io/filesystem.py", line 264, in read
    self._fetch_to_internal_buffer(num_bytes)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/apache_beam/io/filesystem.py", line 218, in _fetch_to_internal_buffer
    while not self._read_eof and (self._read_buffer.tell() -
TypeError: '<' not supported between instances of 'int' and 'NoneType'
```

Following the same code available in doc (below), with the my file location.

```
with beam.Pipeline() as pipeline:
  readable_files = (
      pipeline
      | fileio.MatchFiles('<*filname.patterns>')
      | fileio.ReadMatches()
      | beam.Reshuffle())
  files_and_contents = (
      readable_files
      | beam.Map(lambda x: (x.metadata.path, x.read_utf8())))
```

I tried logging the details, and I've got path name correctly but only the `read_utf8()` gives me this error, what I am missing here?

Comment: Which doc where you following? You accidently used an incorrect link in your post

Comment: sorry about it... [doc](https://beam.apache.org/documentation/patterns/file-processing/) this was the link I was referring to...

Comment: Please do not add answers to the question body itself. Instead, you should add it as an answer. [Answering your own question is allowed and even encouraged](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer).

Answer (score 1):

Solved it, by using ReadAllFromText. Which comes with the option to pass the filename and line to next node and below is the example. Also I was not sure about the above error still...

```
    with beam.Pipeline(options=options) as p:
        # matching files and getting them into PCollection
        readable_files = (
            p
            | MatchFiles(
                "gs://folder/*.csv.gz"
            )
            | ReadMatches(compression=CompressionTypes.GZIP)
            | beam.Reshuffle()
        )

        # extracting path info from FileMetadata
        file_path = readable_files | "extract path" >> beam.Map(
            lambda x: x.metadata.path
        )

        # ReadAllFromText gets the path from PCollection 
        # uses with_filename to include the filename in PColl
        (
            file_path
            | beam.io.ReadAllFromText(skip_header_lines=1, with_filename=True)
            # custom PTransformation 
            | "Dataflow of adjust events"
            >> MyDataFlow(
                user_options.output_table,
                user_options.error_table,
            )
        )
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to access to the filename and content when you are reading text file from `Cloud Storage` with `Beam` `Python`, you can use the following code :

```py
PCollection<KV<String, String>> filesAndLines = 
  p.apply(FileIO.match().filepattern(...))
   .apply(FileIO.read())
   .apply(ParDo.of(new DoFn<ReadableFile, KV<String, String>>() {
     @ProcessElement
     public void process(ProcessContext c) {
       ReadableFile f = c.element();
       String filename = f.getMetadata().resourceId().toString();
       String line;
       try (BufferedReader r = new BufferedReader(Channels.newInputStream(f.open()))) {
         while ((line = r.readLine()) != null) {
           c.output(KV.of(filename, line));
         }
       }
     }
   }));
```

To open `gzip` file, you have the `compression_type` parameter in the `open` method of the `ReadableFile` class :

```py
readable_file.open(compression_type='gzip')
```

Comment: Thank you for the reply, adding compression_type also didn't work for me for some reason... and I figured it out another way to do it..